# Python methods do not show up in user defined functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When creating a user defined function the built-in methods do not pop up as options.

In the main body of the file the methods show up without issue. It's only when you create a function that they do not show up.

```py
def strip_punctuation(astring):
    #punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
    astring.replace()
    return (astring)
```

```py
# Main file
my_string = "Word's!"
my_string.replace()
```

I'd expect the same behavior in VS Code in both a user defined function as well as outside the function.

Comment: Because your text-editor cannot know that `astring` is expected to be `str` object. Python is a dynamically typed language, and there is nothing stopping you from passing any object to `strip_punctuation`, so how do you expect it to know that it should suggest the string methods as opposed to say, list methods? In the case of `my_string = "Words'!"` it can, because you assigned a `str` literal directly. You should consider using type annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrote your code with type annotations you should get what you want:

```py
def strip_punctuation(astring: str) -> str:
    astring.replace()
    return astring
```